# How does the libgdx FrameBuffer work

Tags: java, opengl-es, libgdx, framebuffer

I am currently developing a simple game with libgdx. I am using FrameBuffers to render screen transitions in my game. The code is working perfectly fine normally. The code for handling screen transitions is this (it is in the main game class):

```
 @Override
        public void render () {
            float delta = Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();

            if (nextScreen == null) { // no transition
                if (currentScreen != null) {
                    currentScreen.render(delta);
                }
            } else {
                transitionInProgress = true;
                transitionTime = Math.min(transitionTime + delta, getTransitionDuration());

                // render to texture only once for performance
                if (!renderedToTexture) {
                    renderScreensToTexture();
                    renderedToTexture = true;
                }

                // update transitions
                updateTransitions();
            }
        }

private void updateTransitions() {

        // transition just finished or no transition is specified
        if (screenTransition == null || transitionTime >= getTransitionDuration()) {

            if (currentScreen != null) {
                currentScreen.hide();
                if (nextScreen != null && !(nextScreen instanceof BaseOverlay)) currentScreen.dispose(); // don't dispose the current screen if next screen is instance of BaseOverlay
            }

            // resume next screen
            if (nextScreen != null) {
                nextScreen.resumeLogic();
                Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(nextScreen.getInputProcessor());
            }

            // switch screens and reset
            currentScreen = nextScreen;
            nextScreen = null;
            screenTransition = null;
            currentFrameBuffer.dispose();
            nextFrameBuffer.dispose();
            currentFrameBuffer = null;
            nextFrameBuffer = null;
            renderedToTexture = false;
            transitionInProgress = false;
            return;

        }
        float percentage = transitionTime / getTransitionDuration();
        Gdx.app.log(TAG, "updateTransitions: " + percentage);

        // the textures are auto disposed when the frame buffer objects are disposed
        Texture currentScreenTexture = currentFrameBuffer.getColorBufferTexture(), nextScreenTexture = nextFrameBuffer.getColorBufferTexture();

        // render transition to screen
        transitionSpriteBatch.setProjectionMatrix(transitionViewport.getCamera().combined);
        screenTransition.render(transitionSpriteBatch, currentScreenTexture, nextScreenTexture, percentage);
    }

private void renderScreensToTexture() {
        if (currentScreen != null) {
            currentFrameBuffer.begin();
            currentScreen.render(0); // 0 to render first frame
            currentFrameBuffer.end();
        }

        if (nextScreen != null) {
            nextFrameBuffer.begin();
            nextScreen.render(0);
            nextFrameBuffer.end();
        }
    }
```

The problem is this: the transitions don't work for my screen overlays. I am implementing the screen overlays simply by using screens which render the previous screen in their render method. But once the transition starts, the overlay undergoes the transition perfectly fine, but the screen underneath does not render at all. I think it is to do with the FrameBuffers, but I have just recently learned about them so I do not know much. What could be the solution?

This is the code for my screen overlays:

```
@Override
public void render(float delta) {
    super.render(delta);
    prevScreen.render(delta);   // render the previous screen

    screenUI.renderUI();
}
```

Comment: Hey, did you find answer, since im headbanging at this right now